# Accordion from W3C - how do I open one panel at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I have an accordion where I want to open only one panel at a time.
I need some help to be able to close any open panel when user click to open a closed panel. I guess some javascript is needed for this - I'm afraid I'm not sure how to achieve it though...
I will have more panels than what is shown in the example

**I have the following code:**

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
    background-color: #EA3F8A;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #C11561;
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

#accord {
    margin-bottom: 5.5em;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    
    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the other accordions before you open the one that was clicked.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i, j;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
      acc[j].classList.remove("active");
      acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    if (!this.classList.contains("active")){
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 
    }

  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
    background-color: #EA3F8A;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #C11561;
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

#accord {
    margin-bottom: 5.5em;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    
    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: But then you'll have to add something else to close the current item if you want to close them all.

Comment: Oh - supernice!
Thank you!

Comment: Hmm - I can't close an open panel as before though...
That functionality dissapeared...

Answer (score 1):

I've always found it easier to make my own accordion:

```js
$('.item-title').click(function() {
        $(this).parents().siblings().find('.item-body').slideUp();
        $(this).parents().siblings('.item').find('.item-open-close').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
        $(this).siblings('.item-body').slideToggle();
    });
```

```css
.item-title i {
float:right;
}

.item-title {
    background-color: #EA3F8A;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.item-body {
padding:18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">            
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-title">
      Section 1<i class="fa item-open-close fa-plus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item-body" style="display: none;">
      This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content.   
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-title">
      Section 2<i class="fa item-open-close fa-plus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item-body" style="display: none;">
      This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content.   
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-title">
      Section 3<i class="fa item-open-close fa-plus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item-body" style="display: none;">
      This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content. This is content.   
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Improved @MayK's Answer So that the current Item can be closed.

```
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        for (j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
        if(acc[j] != this) {
           acc[j].classList.remove("active");
           acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
         }
        }
        if (!this.classList.contains("active")){
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.maxHeight){
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
          } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
          } 
        }
    
      });
    }
```